# Stop timer until method is done

Tags: c#, .net, timer

can someone help me to stop timer until the method "Utils.ItsTimeToRemind(remind.FormTag);" is finished? Then start again...

```
public static Timer TIMER; 

public TimerClass()
{
    TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(Tick);
    TIMER = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);
}

static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
{
    List<RemindObject> remList = Utils.Reminds;
    foreach (RemindObject remind in remList)
    {
        if (remind.reminTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
        {
            Utils.ItsTimeToRemind(remind.FormTag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.100).aspx) instead, which supports Start and Stop methods. You can't pause or stop `System.Threading.Timer` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small problem with Neil Knight's solution - it's better to start/stop your timer in a `try-catch` block. If an exception is thrown you can ensure that the timer will be restarted:

```
using System.Timers.Timer;

private static Timer timer; 

static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
{
    try
    {
        timer.Stop();


        List<RemindObject> remList = Utils.Reminds;
        foreach (RemindObject remind in remList)
        {
            if (remind.reminTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
            {

                Utils.ItsTimeToRemind(remind.FormTag);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log exception, etc
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a reference to the `timer` in the `Utils.ItsTimeToRemind` method, so it would become:

`Utils.ItsTimeToRemind(remind.FormTag, ref timer);`

Then, you can just stop the `timer` in the method.

```
public void ItsTimeToRemind(var, ref timer)
{
    timer.Stop();

    //Method stuff

    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass timer by reference? If you are planning just to call its methods passing reference copy is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a different timer, such as this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx which allows you to set Enabled = false (which you could do in entering your Tick (or whatever name you want to call it) method, and do your work, then set Enabled = true, at end of your Tick method.